# Are we exposed to more blue light than any other colour?

Tags: visible-light, scattering, wavelength

it's my first post so nice to meet you all.

Is blue light more abundant on the Earth's surface than any other colour? I know that if this is extended to non-visible EM radiation then radio waves are a contender. The sky is blue because of Rayleigh scattering, etc, but does that also mean that blue is the wavelength of light most abundantly detected at the Earth's surface? The linked graphic certainly suggests so, but I wanted to firm up my sources. Thanks in advance!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#/media/File:Atmospheric_electromagnetic_opacity.svg

Comment: This will sound a bit silly but given that wavelength is continuous can you specify a wavelength range for "blue" and for any other wavelength it is to be compared with?  Also what do you mean by "more abundant"?  More abundant in terms of energy?

Answer (score 2):

When looking at absolute spectral power density - peak is in cyan (around 480-500nm).

Rayleigh scattering does not make blue more abundant. It makes blue more scattered/"redistributed". When you are at noon and sky are clear - most of light from the sun gets to you directly. Some part of blue photons though will reach you scattering 1 or more time in atmosphere. Some blue photons will scatter outside of the planet and will be lost. When sun is low on the horizon - blue gets scattered far away from you and have low probability of reaching you - spectrum shifts to red.

As eye is much more sensitive in green than in blue - green part of solar radiation is most significant contributor to our vision.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Barsmonster, that's really interesting, thanks. And how about first thing in the morning? Would cyan have peak spectral density then?

Comment: In the morning situation is the same as at the evening : right after sunrise spectrum is shifted to red, as blue, cyan and green photons are scattered many kilometers away form you.